# Using the Get-EventSubscriber cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: windows, events, powershell, scripting

I am having a problem for a script I am working on, I must have already dedicated a good 4 hours to this problem, so now I turn here. I have the follow code, shortened it for everyone:

```
while($true){
    $seclog = Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq 'Security'} ;
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $seclog -SourceIdentifier NewEventLogEnter -EventName EntryWritten -Action {
        $entry = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry
        if($entry.EventID -eq 4776){
            if($entry.EntryType -eq 'FailureAudit'){
                $i++;
            }
            elseif($entry.EntryType -eq 'SuccessAudit'){
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$i")
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the script, it works as it need be but I get a powershell console going in an infinite loop saying: **Register-ObjectEvent: could not create subscriber for SourceIdentifier, one exists**. Here is a picture of the error:[Link to my dropbox, where I am hosting the picture.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x629odlgh434l3q/error.PNG)

I do not have enough rep to post picutres yet.

I need this to run in an infinite loop, so after banging my head all day, I think that there might be a way to check all current events created, and see if I could check if the SourceIdentifier is already in use and therefore, we would not create a new instance. Thus solving the issue. I figured I could get this done via the *Get-EventSubscriber* command but im not so sure. This is my first powershell script, so please forgive me for any horrendous things you see in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, but you're mixing up a few things. Perhaps you're getting a bit jumbled up between .NET events as asynchronous callbacks (which would use `Register-ObjectEvent`) and events as records in a log file.

If I am understanding your attempt, you want to count how many failure audits you see until you hit a success, in which case you display the previous count for failure audits. This means you want to work with the type of events that are records in a log file. Take a look at this:

```
$seclog = Get-EventLog -LogName Security

foreach ($entry in $seclog) {        
        if($entry.EventID -eq 4776){
            if($entry.EntryType -eq 'FailureAudit'){
                $i++;
            }
            elseif($entry.EntryType -eq 'SuccessAudit'){
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$i")
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do this in a loop, you'd have to wrap the whole thing in a `while` clause and each time you fetch records from the event log, you should pass in the date and time of the latest record you've previously read.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I am not sure I understand the problem correctly but could you use something like the code below to check whether a source exist, and create it if not?

```
    if (-not([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($source))) {
    ## Write-Host "$source does not exist. Creating new one" 
    [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($source,$logname)    
}
```

Comment: That may work for another thing I plan to work on, however, I updated the question, so hopefully, it's more easier to read. thank you